# Repeat a rhyme and loop on the vowels

Tags: code-golf, string

## Vowels rhyme: Apples and Bananas

There is a traditional children's song that repeats the same text over and over, only each time every vowel is replaced with a random vowel, but constant across the current stanza.

### Challenge

The objective is to propose the shortest code that performs such a transformation on an input text.

### Rules

1. You must print the rhyme as many times as there are distinct vowels in it.
2. Each print must be separated with a line break (platform-specific combo of `\n` and `\r` is accepted).
3. For iteration `i`, replace each vowel with the `i`th distinct vowel in the original text.
4. The input text is a sequence of printable ASCII characters (range `[32, 126]`.
5. Input will not contain embedded line breaks.
6. Only vowels characters must be affected, other must be output exactly as input.
7. Only vowels characters count: nasal vowels, although sounding like vowels (like in French *"Tintin"*), must not be handled as a single vowel.
8. Case matters for the output, but is positional (replacing an uppercase vowel is done with the uppercase replacement vowel)
9. Uppercase vowels are not distinct from their lowercase counterpart (ie `a` <=> `A`)
10. Consecutive vowels are always considered separately (ie. `Boat` yields both `Boot` and `Baat`)
11. Since the letter `y` represents either a vowel or consonant soun (as we're speaking English), handling it as a vowel or a consonant is allowed, however answers must explicitly state whether they handle `y` as a vowel or not.

### Examples:

**Hello world**

```
Hello world!
```

gives:

```
Helle werld!
Hollo world!
```

**Excerpt from the original French text (translated), with `y` handled as a vowel:**

```
An elephant that was rambling all gently in the woods...
```

gives:

```
An alaphant that was ramblang all gantla an tha waads...
En elephent thet wes rembleng ell gentle en the weeds...
In iliphint thit wis rimbling ill gintli in thi wiids...
Yn ylyphynt thyt wys rymblyng yll gyntly yn thy wyyds...
On olophont thot wos romblong oll gontlo on tho woods...
```

Note the behaviour on leading uppercase vowel: case is kept at its index (rules 8 and 9).

**Vowelless example**

Input that does not contain any vowel, like:

```
lgn@hst:~$ rm -rf ./* ~ /
```

must produce no output, or a single line break.

**Single-vowel input**

Input containing a single vowel is output as is.

```
Dad sat at a car and saw a fat bat.
```

gives:

```
Dad sat at a car and saw a fat bat.
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytecount code wins (nothing but eternal PPCG glory)!

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 45 bytes

```
~(K`A\EI\OU
L$`\\?(.)
./$1/i&$*\T`Vv`5*$&$L$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/v07DO8ExxtUzxj@Uy0clISbGXkNPk0tPX8VQP1NNRSsmJCGsLMFUS0VNxUdF7f9/xzyF1JzUgozEvBKFkozEEoXyxGKFosTcpJzMvHSFxJwchfTUvJKcSoXMPKB8qkJ5fn5KsZ6eHgA) Does not count `y` as a vowel. Explanation:

```
K`A\EI\OU
```

Replaces the text with the literal string `A\EI\OU`.

```
L$`\\?(.)
```

Matches each letter optionally preceded by a backslash.

```
./$1/i&$*\T`Vv`5*$&$L$&
```

Outputs a line of Retina code for each letter.

```
~(
```

Evaluates the generated code (shown below) using the original input. The `.` causes the code not to output the (final) buffer. The `/<vowel>/i&` causes the rest of the line to run only if the input contains the given vowel (case-insensitively). The `*` causes the result of the line to be ignored, so that the next vowel can be tested. The `\` causes the result to be printed on its own line before it is ignored. The `` T`Vv`AAAAAa `` transliterates uppercase `V`owels to `AAAAA`s and all lowercase `v`owels to `a`. `\A` is an escape that refers to ASCII 07 (BEL), but `E`, `O` and `o` are built-in character classes that needs to be escaped to give their literal values (`e` is not a character class, but fortunately it is also not an escape.)

```
./A/i&*\T`Vv`AAAAAa
./E/i&*\T`Vv`\E\E\E\E\E\e
./I/i&*\T`Vv`IIIIIi
./O/i&*\T`Vv`\O\O\O\O\O\o
./U/i&*\T`Vv`UUUUUu
```

Comment: Mmh, self-generating code. I don't know Retina well but that's impressive!

Comment: @joH1 Well, for me the impressive bit is that it saved 60 bytes!

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 78 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.downcase.scan(/[aeiou]/).uniq.map{|v|s.tr"AEIOUaeiou",v.upcase*5+v}*?\n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw5a8NAEIX7/IrJkiKR41HlJpDDYINTpUplqxhJqwNWs8rOroTx8deVVSBgeM373uFCfpyq12n5JifB0o5ckGiUgvgx3ZNubcjSJwzc/mBH/ek8nAW9U@vt59f3X6yeBwz9vEpWi@GSvB/4MvXBC1R7tdPGWBitM@W9yu7@8ZpBG903xB58Qx5GEnDU5ablGsgYqDV7c4SWY67jgS0FEW8uNlSCxOUsKMgB8QzG6KrIcvK3bVPzRyP@5foAroOlqwDTBK6Qqmz6BQ)

A quick and naive approach. Y is not considered a vowel.

Answer (score 4):

## Japt v2.0a0 `-R`, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

Treats `y` as a vowel. Change both occurences of `\y` to `\v` to treat it as a consonant.

```
v f\y â £r\y_Xc^H*ZøZu
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=diBmXHkg4iCjclx5X1hjXkgqWvhadQ==&input=IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISIKLVI=)

---

### Explanation

```
v                          :Lowercase
   \y                      :RegEx /[aeiouy]/gi (\v is /[aeiou]/gi)
  f                        :Get all matches as an array
      â                    :Deduplicate
        £                  :Map each X
         r\y               :  Replace all matches of the RegEx above in the input
             _             :  Pass matches through a function as Z
              Xc^          :    XOR the character code of X with
                 H*        :     32 multiplied by
                   Zø      :     Does Z contain
                     Zu    :      Uppercase Z
                           :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

Answer (score 4):

### bash, 96 bytes

Two equal-length solutions:

```bash
v=aeiouAEIOU;for x in `grep -o [$v]<<<$1|sed 's/./\L&&&&&\U&/'|awk !a[\\$0]++`;{ tr $v $x<<<$1;}
v=aeiouAEIOU;for x in `tr -cd $v<<<$1|sed 's/./\L&&&&&\U&\n/g'|awk !a[\\$0]++`;{ tr $v $x<<<$1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc1BC4IwHIbxr/IGQw/SrLN28NAhCDp5UsG/uFRam2xLjeyzL@y5/3gasr3304nEoF/Z@XLLk7s2WDAo1J0RI/YaBZuqNE3ZcbWiRWhjHpfXYKvMgzhcaX5gR0VZskMVRXXygTNgE9jyV8nXe58pCCnGnpSD68lhJgtDz0YOqgNJiU4oJ9/b2PUCs9at5Zz/AA)

Takes input as a command line argument and outputs to STDOUT.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

(Indirectly) saved one byte thanks to [Kevin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) (printing directly inside the loop rather than joining, only work in the legacy version).

```
lžMÃÙεžMDu«s5×Du«‡=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/5@g@38PNh2ee2wpkuJQeWl1seng6iH7UsND2/3/HPIXUnNSCjMS8EoWSjMQShfLEYoWixNyknMy8dIXEnByF9NS8kpxKhcw8oHyqQnl@fkqxnp4eAA)

#### Using the Elixir rewrite,  20 bytes

```
lžMÃÙεžMDu«s5×Du«‡}»
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5@g@38PNh2ee2wpkuJQeWl1seng6iH7UsLD20O7//x3zFFJzUgsyEvNKFEoyEksUyhOLFYoSc5NyMvPSFRJzchTSU/NKcioVMvOA8qkK5fn5KcV6enoA)** (without `y`) | **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5@g@/8PNh2ee2wpkuJQeWl1sdng6iH7UsLD20O7//x3zFFJzUgsyEvNKFEoyEksUyhOLFYoSc5NyMvPSFRJzchTSU/NKcioVMvOA8qkK5fn5KcV6enoA)** (with `y`, `žM` being replaced by `žO` – same applies for the legacy version)

#### How it works

```
lžMÃÙεžMDu«s5×Du«‡}»     Full program. Example: "Hello"
l                        Convert the input to lowercase. "Hello" –> "hello"
 žMÃ                     Keep only lowercase vowels. "hello" –> "eo"
    Ù                    Remove duplicates. "eo" –> "eo"
     ε            }      For each of the characters (example with "e"):
      žMDu«              Yield "aeiouAEIOU"
           s5×           Swap, and repeat the current char 5 times. "e" –> "eeeee"
              Du«        Duplicate, uppercase and merge. "eeeee" –> "eeeeeEEEE"
                 ‡       Transliteration. For each item in B, replace it in A with
                         the corresponding item in C.
                   »     Join on newlines.
```

Comment: Nice answer, shorter than the [21 byte answer](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5@g@/@BDKw83H57pcqQhs@zQzkPrKq0OrSutLLXS@f/fMU8hNSe1ICMxr0ShJCOxRKE8sVihKDE3KSczL10hMSdHIT01rySnUiEzDyifqlCen59SrKenBwA) I prepared. You can golf one more byte by looping and printing instead of mapping: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5@g@38PNh2eWAWmX0kOrK00PTwfRjxoW6vz/75inkJqTWpCRmFeiUJKRWKJQnlisUJSYm5STmZeukJiTo5CemleSU6mQmQeUT1Uoz89PKdbT0wMA). Your TIO with `y` should also use `6` instead of `5`, btw.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Edited, thanks! About the `y`-vowel version, I accidentally copied the wrong TIO link when I answered :|...

Comment: Ah, now I know again why I had the `i` in my code.. Your answer fails for inputs without vowels. Expected is an empty output, but it actually prints the input itself.. :(

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The 20-byter works, so I rolled back and fixed the second link.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>23 20 18</s>  17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 Thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

```
ØcŒHZx5fƇðØc,yð€Y
```

To treat `y` as a vowel replace both `c`s with `y`s.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY0xDoJAFESvMqGxEZsfKzorrTUx2n3AZTErP1kWcFsbeysPYeEdiB7Ei6yr3Uzy3szxYIwPYbwXr9tyf56r93V8xjb14/NzeexCCMlGE/KudWzLSQtGT9YjrysoGUyGra4LDc0tLHFcQyO/1EoDJ6jsH1pzTyWUlROcZofhLw3SmRI5ZViZ1FBa1S6tTykXPsPCR5KizwVBVPxVYl3XsCP0MpCZJV8)**

#### How?

```
ØcŒHZx5fƇðØc,yð€Y - Link: list of characters, S
Øc                - vowels -> "AEIOUaeiou"
  ŒH              - split in half -> ["AEIOU", "aeiou"]
    Z             - transpose -> ["Aa", "Ee", "Ii", "Oo", "Uu"]
     x5           - times 5 -> ["AAAAAaaaaa", "EEEEEeeeee", "IIIIIiiiii", "OOOOOooooo", "UUUUUuuuuu"]
        Ƈ         - filter keep if:
       f          -   filter keep only -> those of X which have required vowels
                  -                       ...i.e. if S = "blah" then ["AAAAAaaaaa"]
         ð    ð€  - dyadic chain for €ach:
          Øc      -   vowels -> "AEIOUaeiou"
            ,     -   pair       e.g. ["AEIOUaeiou","AAAAAaaaaa"]
             y    -   translate  e.g. swap A for A, E for A, ...
                Y - join with newlines
```

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY0hDsJAFESvMsFgKOYHVUNQoCEh4H5btluy9CfbbctaDB7FIRDcoYGDcJFlwU0m780cD8b4EIZ7/rot9@eZel8n88/lEYvh6WPYhRBGG03I2saxLcYNGB1Zj6wqoaQ3Kba6yjU0N7DEcQ@1/FIjNZygtH9ozR0VUFZOcJod@r/US2sKZJRiZRJDSVm5pDolnPsUCx9Jij7nBFHxV4l1bc2O0ElPZjr6Ag) (trivial) (`ż/` on a pair is `Z`, two dyads in a row where the left one is unpaired in a monad have the argument in-between implicitly)

Comment: Thanks (`Z` >_<), not sure what was going on with my TIO session, but removing the redundant `ð` wasn't working; restart fixed.

Comment: TBH, I actually fixed `x€` → `x` too, but you ninja'd me. :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 229 bytes

Taking `y` for a non-vowel

```
func[s][v: charset"aoeiu"w: charset"AOEIU"p: copy""parse s[any[[copy c[v | w](if not find p c[append p c lowercase c
parse s[any[[copy n to[v | w | end]](prin n)opt[v(prin c)|[w(prin uppercase copy c)]| skip]]]print""])]| skip]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY6xasUwDEX3fMWtp5clH/C2NxTaqVDoZDy4tvJi6srGdmIC@ffUaQotdBBIR9wjJbL7K1mpuvG6jzMbmZVcrjCTTpmK0IHcLOovuL08Pr@J2ECIqxDxoMhS8yrlgWDkgg1VXdwIDgWjY4vYsI6RzhY@VEpGt6Tp/hsYJZySVi2i1CUmx@A@xCKXczD9JuvZzk38Y/t@oFcb8oeLSqljX4RQf9A@QjyR9wE1JG8fRNfAjUGe4qS5oEy6oOqMpD/fveM7tPe4Exe/op0rE7VosHkYBrF/AQ)

Slightly more readable:

```
f: func [ s ] [
    v: charset "aoeiu"
    w: charset "AOEIU"
    p: copy ""
    parse s[ 
        any [
            [ copy c [ v | w ]
                ( if not find p c [ 
                    append p c
                    lowercase c
                    parse s [
                        any [
                            [ copy n to [ v | w | end ] ]
                                 ( prin n )
                            opt [ v ( prin c )
                                | [ w ( prin uppercase copy c ) ]
                                | skip
                                ]
                            ] 
                        ]
                    print ""
                ] )
            ]
            | skip
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>138</s>, 129 bytes

```r
function(x,U=utf8ToInt,a=U(V<-'aeiouAEIOU'))for(i in (which(a%in%U(x))-1)%%5)cat(chartr(V,intToUtf8(rep(a[i+c(1,6)],e=5)),x),'
')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc2xbsIwEIDhnae4Ropyp5pIDFQdmoEBCaYumA5Vh6uxsSX3jMxFSZ8@pQ/wf39dwrCEUZymIjgbO4waXk/lKGp4sHh@W3fsUxl3@@O77YhCqZggCeAUk4vIbZLW4ky03lDbbsmxootcteLZJNFTsQ8Rq78hf6ZnhxvzQl/GD1siM5PpVh0tAZudgM/@FlkUNLLCxHeo/POdk1yBc4arF82//2@NHqZSLve@7xtaPeqDz7nAR6n5Ak8NLX8)

- `y` is not considered a vowel

Answer (score 2):

### Python, <strike>129</strike> <strike>119</strike> 112 bytes

```
import re
f=lambda s:'\n'.join(r('[AEIOU]',v.upper(),r('[aeiou]',v,s))for v in'aeiou'if v in s.lower());r=re.sub
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxDsIgEIDh3adgO0gIi5umg4OJTp2c1IGmEM9QjhzQxqfH0PH/kj/9yofisTVcEnER7A5@CHaZZivyCV4RzJcwSpbwvFzv4@MNejU1JcdS6a7WIdWuOivlicUqMMKugH4vkU2grR/qzAM7k@vUEmMs0ku4uRBIbCOHGZRqfw)

Doesn't treat \$y\$ as vowel.

-7 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder

Comment: Glad to see you could get it working and golfed down a bit! Nice work

Comment: [112 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcuxDsIgEIDh3adgO0gIi5umg4OJTp2c1IGmEM9QjhzQxqfH0PH/kj/9yofisTVcEnER7A5@CHaZZivyCV4RzJcwSpbwvFzv4@MNejU1JcdS6a7WIdWuOivlicUqMMKugH4vkU2grR/qzAM7k@vUEmMs0ku4uRBIbCOHGZRqfw).

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 99 bytes

Treats \$y\$ as a consonant.

```javascript
s=>(g=F=>Buffer(s).map(c=>2130466>>c&c>64?F(c):c)+`
`)(v=>g[v&=31]||(g[v]=S+=g(c=>c&96|v)),S='')&&S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU1ba8MgFH7vrzgrI9V1tetaAivoLozS9zyOQq1Rk2E0qEsYhP71zLyOwnn4znf95h0PwtdtXFlXylHRMVCGND1Q9vGjlPQoYNLwFgnKnjfbp12eMyYywfLd6wEJvBd4eZ6dMeoo019dRreb0zCgBE@0WFI95UT2kg8dxo8FXSxwlhWjcDY4I4lxGik0P0pjHPTOm/JujvHsn/xuQRrZVtxGiBWP0PMAnjcXU1sN3BjQ0kbzC7VNukxFrgyEkBtVRtu3KsT99R58AyuvgKwf4ArrG95PXkJIa9OB4B64nYg@fSpxFx6nhfEP)

#### Commented

```javascript
s => (                   // s = input string
  g = F =>               // g = helper function taking a callback function F
    Buffer(s)            // turn s into a Buffer
    .map(c =>            // for each ASCII code c in s:
      2130466            //   2130466 is a vowel bitmask: 1000001000001000100010
                         //                               u     o     i   e   a
      >> c               //   the ECMAScript specification enforces that the shiftCount is
                         //   the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits
      & c > 64           //   also make sure to ignore non-letter characters
      ?                  //   if a vowel is identified:
        F(c)             //     invoke F with c
      :                  //   else:
        c                //     just yield c
    ) + `\n`             // end of map(); coerce back to a string and append a newline
  )(v =>                 // invoke g with a callback that takes v:
    g[v &= 31] || (      //   unless this vowel has already been encountered:
      g[v] =             //     mark it as encountered
      S +=               //     and append to the output string S
      g(                 //     the result of another call to g:
        c => c & 96 | v  //       where vowels are replaced with v, using the original case
      )                  //     end of inner call to g
    ),                   //
    S = ''               //   start with S = ''
  ) && S                 // end of outer call to g; return S
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>196</s> 188 bytes

```java
s->{var d=new int[99];for(var c:s.toUpperCase().replaceAll("[^AEIOU]","").toCharArray())if(d[c]++<1)System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[AEIOU]",c+"").replaceAll("[aeiou]",(char)(c+32)+""));}
```

-8 bytes thanks to *@joH1*.

Without `y` as vowel to save bytes.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZHBbsIwDIbvPIVX7ZCMEbTtBB3TKjZpO4wdECfUSSZNaVlIqyRQIQSv3rmsOyDtgBRFsh1/9v9nhVvsrZLvWmp0Dj4wN/sOQG68silKBZMmBNgWeQKSTb3NzRIcDyl76NDlPPpcwgQMjKB2vaf9Fi0kI6OqhjIfDOIwLSxrsnLohC9mZansGJ1iXFhVapoSac2C@Vf0@v45i4PbIOD0bpyhjazFHeM8T1kyl3G3@3jHpzvn1VoUGy9K2sZrw9w56I8juw3prIQqLzZUYpLonMnuwz1vXvHwUIeNnnKz0KSnlXWSvSZTWuXzGJD/OmKEZMGb0rqAqrA6uQpOpgD8s19bObVEBpRWZYbGg8/QQ4UOLK5pLDmLWsNSUdOO3KO6IniROCHEhfgXTMARtTkgyXQ0TaKiKKXcAv2lJL00z5nzw@M12DX0bAqifwNH6Aft7x/qHw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                       // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  var d=new int[99];       //  Integer-array indicating which vowels we've already output
  for(var c:s.toUpperCase()//  Convert the input to uppercase
            .replaceAll("[^AEIOU]","")
                           //  Remove all non-vowels
            .toCharArray())//  Convert it to a character array)
                           //  And loop over those vowel-characters
    if(d[c]++              //   Increase the vowel-count by 1
             <1)           //   And if it was 0 this iteration:
      System.out.println(  //    Print with trailing newline:
        s                  //     The input,
         .replaceAll("[AEIOU]",c+"")
                           //     with every uppercase vowel replace with the current vowel
         .replaceAll("[aeiou]",(char)(c+32)+""));}
                           //     and every lowercase vowel replaced as well
```

Comment: [188 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZHBbsIwDIbvPIVX7ZCMEbTtBB3TKjZpO4wdECfUSSZNaVlIqyRQIQSv3rmsOyDtgBRFsh1/9v9nhVvsrZLvWmp0Dj4wN/sOQG68silKBZMmBNgWeQKSTb3NzRIcDyl76NDlPPpcwgQMjKB2vaf9Fi0kI6OqhjIfDOIwLSxrsnLohC9mZansGJ1iXFhVapoSac2C@Vf0@v45i4PbIOD0bpyhjazFHeM8T1kyl3G3@3jHpzvn1VoUGy9K2sZrw9w56I8juw3prIQqLzZUYpLonMnuwz1vXvHwUIeNnnKz0KSnlXWSvSZTWuXzGJD/OmKEZMGb0rqAqrA6uQpOpgD8s19bObVEBpRWZYbGg8/QQ4UOLK5pLDmLWsNSUdOO3KO6IniROCHEhfgXTMARtTkgyXQ0TaKiKKXcAv2lJL00z5nzw@M12DX0bAqifwNH6Aft7x/qHw) by inlining the variable `v` in the loop

Comment: @joH1 Thanks, not sure how I missed that..

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 112 bytes

```python
s=input()
V='aeiouAEIOU'
for v in V:
 if v in s.lower():print''.join([c,[v.upper(),v][c>'Z']][c in V]for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BagIxEIbP7lNMoTBaNEKPi0qFWtqTl9ZCxUN2d9ZNG5Mwybp68dW3iRYaQjL5P@bLuHNorHnsS1sRzIERsfdzZVwbhqNsM0dJyrbL1dv6A7PaMhxBGdjkGaj6VnuhbUc8HOWOlQmI4tsqM9yW4@1RtM4lND7utuUCv3AX76tgl1zX0o/6@GnWNUoTvHNLeTYIfI7n4CoEnM0mt4UxoxOVkKb95390sYicTiW5AKv1y4rZcrIUTPIn6/GVtLbwaVlXd5jh0gBpco2MitDIAJ30wPJQaGX2ILWGPZmgz2nG0BB01lZeCBFb9d48NT7kl3vgA0y4BjF9gAtMI3uWFfhoSxtKySBNCrr4qmNWyCDwFw)

Treats `y` as a consonant.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 64 bytes

```perl6
{m:g:i/<[aeiou]>/».lc.unique».&{$^v;say S:g:ii[<[aeiou]>]=$v}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcqxTgJBFIXhnqc4xYbVxAydBYiJ0c6SkqC5sHd3bjJzB2dmISvhWWx8Czt5sHVo7E7@7@w5uvvRD5i2WI4nP@/mMntYE0voN4@z3x/jdqZX@ei57OmpejssEg1YXY@y/n9ultXhfB7bm@r9Fm2Ik/olsuDZinJihZeMhj1eg@ZIW0oJiS5fRahvi0SsSi8BvTbg@Hn5ti4XTrKzOFIy9d2kflKw470lzciW8hUQyW@daAdyDh1rdgNEizOOITTJGFMvxj8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 184 bytes

y is a vowel

```java
s->s.chars().mapToObj(c->""+(char)(c>96?c:c+32)).filter("aeiouy"::contains).distinct().forEach(c->System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[aeiouy]",c).replaceAll("[AEIOUY]",c.toUpperCase())))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BawIxFIT/SsgpqfUdWihU2y0iHnooHqyHIj08s08322wSkreKiL99G7GXznEGvplp8YDjEMm39c9guxgSi7Z40LN1sOu9YRs83E2Nw5zFB1p/zoxsjZgHn/uO0suKk/X7Kr0OeVxlMA2mrDR0GD/DctsqM66kHKmrr5Wpnp/ezMSMHh@0hp11TElJJBv6k5xMTPBcOrKG2ma2pb6QdiEt0DRX0OqUmToIPUMsrey8ypAoOjQ0c07JzQ31Le@N/h/MFu/L9dc1AA7rGCnNMZPSRcM09ltXPv1dOwRbi67sULdvm2/U5wRoDEVWcuYFOYoNehbcIIsjZpGwKwi/F@ic2FOZdhLWl5zEMYQ6A4DU08tl@AU)